# Zend mail - cannot read - connection closed?

Tags: laravel, email, zend-framework, gmail, imap

Using the zend mail php package to connect to Gmail and getting an error

My Method looks like

```
//Get all mail
    public function GetMail() {
        $mail = new Imap([
            'host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'port' => '993',
            'user'     => 'example@gmail.com',
            'password' => '*********',
        ]);

        echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
        foreach ($mail as $message) {
            printf("Mail from '%s': %s\n", $message->from, $message->subject);
        }
    }
```

The error is as follows:
cannot read - connection closed?

Using Laravel as a framework

Answer (score 1):

So i fixed using

```
 $mail = new Imap(array(
            'host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
            'user' => 'noreply@gmail.com',
            'password' => '*********',
            'ssl' => 'ssl',
            'port' => 993
        ));

        $mail->countMessages();
        $content = array();
        foreach ($mail as $messageNum => $message) {
            array_push($content, ['from' => $message->from,'subject' => $message->subject, 'id' => $message->messageId]);
        }
        return $content;
```